Paginated results from an API in Power Query
A friendly developer has helped me create an API for a system he's built for me, so I can export the data into Power BI.
I've managed to import it, but  I'm running into a problem that the bigger data sets result in a line in the JsonResponse applied step that ends with some code: ?top=200&skip=200.
I've learned that this is to do with pagination, and that it's important to efficiently retrieve the data. But my tables are all limited to 200 rows.
How do I get the rest of the data?
This is the code in the advanced editor that I'm currently using (this was generated with the help of ChatGPT, I'm quite skilled with the copy and paste buttons, but don't really know what I'm looking at):
    let
url = "https://finder.bloodsandbeyond.co.uk/myurl",
headers = [
#"x-api-token-name" = "x-api-token", // Add this line if it is required
#"x-api-token" = "????????????????????????????" // Replace with your actual API key],
source = Web.Contents(url, [Headers=headers]),
jsonResponse = Json.Document(source),
value = jsonResponse[value],
#"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(value, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
#"Expanded Column1" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Converted to Table", "Column1", {"id", "lab_id", "assigned_user_id", "lab_invoice_id", "user_invoice_id", "appointment_at", "matched_at", "sample_posted_at", "is_under_18", "is_urgent", "patient_fee", "patient_cost", "collections_fee", "collections_cost", "reference", "status", "status_reason", "name", "address_line_1", "address_line_2", "city", "post_code", "lat", "lng", "phone", "email", "patients", "preferred_datetimes", "notes", "admin_notes", "deleted_at", "created_at", "updated_at", "confirmed_at", "is_issue", "invoice_notes", "issue_type"}, {"id", "lab_id", "assigned_user_id", "lab_invoice_id", "user_invoice_id", "appointment_at", "matched_at", "sample_posted_at", "is_under_18", "is_urgent", "patient_fee", "patient_cost", "collections_fee", "collections_cost", "reference", "status", "status_reason", "name", "address_line_1", "address_line_2", "city", "post_code", "lat", "lng", "phone", "email", "patients", "preferred_datetimes", "notes", "admin_notes", "deleted_at", "created_at", "updated_at", "confirmed_at", "is_issue", "invoice_notes", "issue_type"})
in
#"Expanded Column1"

Chat GPT has come up with a few other ideas, but at best it just ends up resulting in 200 rows again:
let
// Initial URL
initialUrl = "https://finder.bloodsandbeyond.co.uk/myURL",

// Function to fetch each page of data
GetAppointments = (url as text) as table =>
let
    // Fetch the data from the API
    source = Json.Document(Web.Contents(url, [Headers = [#"x-api-token" = "?????????????????????????"]])),
    // Extract the value part of the response
    value = source[value],
    // Check if there's a next link for pagination
    nextLink = try source[#"@odata.nextLink"] otherwise null,
    // Convert the result to a table
    result = Table.FromList(value, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
    // Expand the columns in the result
    expanded = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(result, "Column1", {"id", "lab_id", "assigned_user_id", "lab_invoice_id", "user_invoice_id", "appointment_at", "matched_at", "sample_posted_at", "is_under_18", "is_urgent", "patient_fee", "patient_cost", "collections_fee", "collections_cost", "reference", "status", "status_reason", "name", "address_line_1", "address_line_2", "city", "post_code", "lat", "lng", "phone", "email", "patients", "preferred_datetimes", "notes", "admin_notes", "deleted_at", "created_at", "updated_at", "confirmed_at", "is_issue", "invoice_notes", "issue_type"}),
    // If there's more data, recursively fetch the next page
    finalResult = if nextLink <> null then
        Table.Combine({expanded, @GetAppointments(nextLink)})
    else
        expanded
in
    finalResult,

// Call the function to get all the data automatically
allData = GetAppointments(initialUrl)

in
allData
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

https://gorilla.bi/power-query/list-generate-api-calls/

There are at least ten questions in this forum on this topic with accepted answers. What was the problem with those?

I've been through those, and I think the problem is that the api is so bespoke that I wasn't able to get there through the user friendly getdata > api key route, I had to write this custom code in a custom query to get it to work at all. When I say I had to, I mean Chat GPT had to.
So now I've created myself a very specific and unique problem, and the only fix will specifically involve changing this code.

For example, the link above doesn't work for me because I fall at the first hurdle. If I try to call the api with a getdata > from web, it literlaly just brings back a 404 webpage. It's something to do with the x-api-token-name needs to be defined in the head. That's why I ended up having to do a custom query.

Does it make a difference that this link is talking about JSON, but my link for the data is oData?

There are also lots of solutions for retrieving then using tokens to access pages

I think without the api documentation, it will be difficult to assist.

I got there in the end, chat gpt did eventually work for me, after a bit of debugging and error handling.
For anyone in the same boat, hopefully this code can help.
    let
    // Define the Table.GenerateByPage function for pagination
    Table.GenerateByPage = (getNextPage as function) as table =>
    let        
        listOfPages = List.Generate(
            () => getNextPage(0),            // Start with the first page (skip=0)
            (lastPage) => lastPage <> null,  // Stop when null is returned (no more data)
            (lastPage) => getNextPage(Table.RowCount(lastPage)) // Pass the row count as the next skip value
        ),
        // Concatenate the pages together
        tableOfPages = Table.FromList(listOfPages, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), {"Column1"}),
        firstRow = tableOfPages{0}?
    in
        // If no pages are returned, return an empty table
        if (firstRow = null) then
            Table.FromRows({})
        else if (Table.IsEmpty(firstRow[Column1])) then
            firstRow[Column1]
        else
            Value.ReplaceType(
                Table.ExpandTableColumn(tableOfPages, "Column1", Table.ColumnNames(firstRow[Column1])),
                Value.Type(firstRow[Column1])
            ),

    // Define the getNextPage function with enhanced error handling
    getNextPage = (skipCount as number) =>
    let
        // Construct the API URL with pagination logic
        url = "https://finder.bloodsandbeyond.co.uk/myURL?$skip=" & Number.ToText(skipCount),
        headers = [
            #"x-api-token" = "?????????????????????????"
        ],
        source = try Web.Contents(url, [Headers=headers]) otherwise null,
        // Convert the response to text and parse it as JSON
        rawResponse = if source = null then error "No data from API!" else Text.FromBinary(source),
        jsonResponse = try Json.Document(rawResponse) otherwise null,
        // Check if the "value" field exists and is valid
        value = if jsonResponse = null or not Record.HasFields(jsonResponse, "value") then null else jsonResponse[value],
        // If value is null or empty, stop fetching further pages
        nextPage = if value = null or List.IsEmpty(value) then null else value
    in
        // Return the result as a table or null
        if nextPage = null then null else Table.FromList(nextPage, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),

    // Use Table.GenerateByPage to get all data
    allData = Table.GenerateByPage(getNextPage)
in
    allData


Forget that. Turned out that was just repeating the same 200 rows over and over again. :(
Back to the drawing board, but we came up with this result instead:
let
// Function to get all pages
GetAllPages = () =>
let
    // Function to get the next page
    GetNextPage = (skipCount as number) =>
    let
        url = "https://finder.bloodsandbeyond.co.uk/odata/myURL?$skip=" & Number.ToText(skipCount),
        headers = [
            #"x-api-token" = "????????????????"
        ],
        source = try Web.Contents(url, [Headers=headers]) otherwise null,
        // Convert response to JSON
        jsonResponse = if source = null then error "No data from API!" else try Json.Document(source) otherwise null,
        // Check if jsonResponse is valid
        value = if jsonResponse <> null and Record.HasFields(jsonResponse, "value") then jsonResponse[value] else null,

        // Debugging: Log the URL and the number of records fetched
        _ = if value <> null then
            let
                recordCount = List.Count(value),
                debugMessage = "Fetched " & Number.ToText(recordCount) & " records from: " & url
            in
                // Uncomment the next line to display debug messages in the console
                // Debug.WriteLine(debugMessage)
                null
            else
                null

    in
        // Return the records as a table or null if no records
        if value = null or List.IsEmpty(value) then null else Table.FromList(value, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),

    // Initialize variables
    pages = {}, // List to hold pages
    currentPage = GetNextPage(0), // Start with the first page
    skipCount = 0, // Initialize skip count

    // Loop to fetch pages until there are no more records
    Result = List.Generate(
        () => [Page = currentPage, Skip = skipCount], // Start with the first page
        each [Page] <> null, // Continue while there's a valid page
        each [Page = GetNextPage([Skip] + 200), Skip = [Skip] + 200], // Get the next page and update skip count
        each [Page] // Return the current page
    ),

    // Combine all pages into a single table
    allData = Table.Combine(List.RemoveNulls(Result))
in
    allData,

// Call the function to get all the data
Result = GetAllPages(),
#"Expanded Column1" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(Result, "Column1", {"id", "invoice_id", "source", "state", "transaction_id", "amount", "created_at", "updated_at", "deleted_at"}, {"id", "invoice_id", "source", "state", "transaction_id", "amount", "created_at", "updated_at", "deleted_at"})
in
#"Expanded Column1"

